# Do web frameworks check authorization headers before reading the body?

Tags: web-services, http, frameworks, http-headers, web-frameworks

I was wondering if web frameworks like Flask, Django, Akka HTTP, or Spring check headers before reading the body of the request.

I can have a web server endpoint that is used to upload some files, eg user avatar.
Presumably, I could bump the server with huge files but without Auth headers and slow it down.

I think the server should first check if user is authorized / if headers are fine before reading the body into the memory.
How do web frameworks solve this problem? Where can I read more how is it handled?

Answer (score 3):

Web frameworks are designed to flexibly handle a large number of use cases. One of these use cases is uploading large files. Any mature framework will have a mechanism for handling this use-case without consuming large amounts of memory, usually by storing the data to disk. Some also expose a method for application handlers to access the raw byte stream directly.

Under the hood frameworks read the headers first. They will typically hand the request off to the application handler after parsing the headers. Authorization is then handled by the app. Most frameworks will expose some method of accessing the raw data stream of the bytes, but the more convenient method is to read and parse the data into convenience structures upon the application's first request for data. Applications may need to configure the framework not to do that. Often, frameworks allow applications to set a max upload size. Above that size, and the client receives an error.

Each framework's documentation can provide details on uploads. Here is the upload documentation for each of the frameworks you specified:

- [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/patterns/fileuploads/)
- [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/)
- [Akka HTTP](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/file-upload-directives/fileUploadAll.html)
- [Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)

Comment: ok, but it doesn't need to be file upload. I can do POST /users with 100MB body full of rubbish. What in that case? There is some default request length limit?

Comment: And I assume that my service gets headers first and only some promise/future of the body? And this body is read when I try to access it in the handler? And where is it buffered since then? Is it cached in tcp buffer until I parse headers? Or maybe http sends  headers first and then server asks for the rest ie sending HTTP 100 Continue?

Comment: A file upload is a POST in a parseable format. Again, you really have to look at the documentation for your specific framework to see how it exposes the raw stream to you, but the standard HTTP case is that the request data will be held in the TCP buffer until the application reads it. Whether that read happens because the framework does it for you or because your app tells the framework how and when it is ready to read it is dependent on how you program your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So Is it possible to bump the server with requests with huge body payload (for example huge json data) and it will be put into the tcp buffer and could slow down or kill the server?

Comment: @Mateusz Unlikely. The OS will manage buffers for you and drop packets when buffers fill. TCP and the OS managing it will prevent the application from getting overwhelemed.